# Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread. for IAP in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, dispatch-async

I am using in app purchase in my application,

**code:** i have added IAP in signin and capability and added subscription in appstore connect and used below code.. its working fine in iOS 13 **but its hitting crash in `iOS 15.2`.. like below out put screen its showing and then its crashed**

i have added `DispatchQueue.main.async` in some places but still no luck its crashing... for IAP i am not getting enough refarances also, please guide me

```
import StoreKit
import UIKit
class BuyProfileBoosterVC: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

var products = [SKProduct]()
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    products = response.products
    showSingleButtonWithMessage(title: "Alert", message: "You have total \(products.count) product in App Store connect.", buttonName: "Okay")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
}

enum Products: String, CaseIterable {
    case threeDays
}
// MARK: - Popup related
func fetchProduct() {
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(Products.allCases.compactMap({$0.rawValue})))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}
func buyProduct(productId: String) {
    fetchProduct()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
            paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productId
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
        }
        else {
            self.view.makeToast("You can't make payment.")
        }
    }
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        transactions.forEach { (transaction) in
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing: self.view.makeToast("Transaction started.")
            case .purchased, .restored: self.view.makeToast("Transaction successful/restored.")
            case .failed, .deferred: self.view.makeToast("Transaction failed.")
            @unknown default: self.view.makeToast("Unknown state.")
            }
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func jumpBuyAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.fetchProduct()
        self.buyProduct(productId: "threeDay")
    }
}
}
```

**Error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

[Out put of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqJzl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/) is the best resource for IAP in IOS but also you can have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.kodeco.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started) if you want to find a relatively easy one.

About the crash, as there is not much information available from your code but it might be crashing on **showSingleButtonWithMessage** function call, This is something that is supposed to be done on main thread( assuming this shows an alert controller ) and where it is called in your code, it might be getting called on background thread. Try calling it on main thread.